# Netty SSL Handshake

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, netty

I am trying to build a sample server using netty which will handle ssl data as well.

Have created SSLContext as below

```
 File privateKey = new File("privatekey.pem");
 File publicKey =  new File("certificate.pem");
 SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(publicKey,privateKey)
            .build();
```

After creating ssl context I have added the same into my pipeline as below

```
SSLEngine engine = sslCtx.newEngine(ch.alloc());
ch.pipeline().addLast(new SslHandler(engine, true),<other custom handlers>);
```

I have also imported the certificate.pem into client software. Still whenever I am initiating any connection i get below logs in server log.

```
    io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:472)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:405)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:372)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:355)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(SslHandler.java:1054)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelInactive(LoggingHandler.java:167)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1429)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:947)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:826)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:474)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1647)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1615)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1781)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1070)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:896)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:766)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:295)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1301)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1203)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1247)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    ... 22 more
```

Can someone please guide what am I doing wrong here? Or any implementation for reference.

Netty Version - 4.1.32

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you exercise your server? (What is the nature of the client?)